# building v8 engine with Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, v8, embedded-v8

Sorry about english mistakes) Please help. I try build v8 engine from "Hellow world" example. It will be embedded on my base project, so i am need build it with Cmake, (system is macOS Sierra). I compiled v8 engine (build libraries by default stored in out directory) and i have following file system structure:

[screen file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6gE1.png)

As showed in example it later most build with this make expression :

```
g++ -I. hello_world.cpp -o hello_world -Wl,--start-group out/x64.release/obj.target/{tools/gyp/libv8_{base,libbase,external_snapshot,libplatform},third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n,data}}.a -Wl,--end-group -lrt -ldl -pthread -std=c++0x
```

also, please look at my CMakeLists.txt file:

[screen CMakeLists.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuLYs.jpg)

On build i have the following error output:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: Does homebrew `v8` formula works for you? If you need latest v8 version have a look at my `v8@5.7` formula under [pinepain/devtools](https://github.com/pinepain/homebrew-devtools) tap. It is less likely you want to build it alongside your project as recent versions build libbase and others as dynamic, so it is much simpler now. To build hello world see [hello_world_build_osx.sh](https://github.com/pinepain/php-v8/blob/upgrade-to-v8-5.7/scripts/test_v8/hello_world_build_osx.sh) script I use to test v8 build (note, you may want to specify proper `ROOT` path).

Comment: Can you please publish what symbols are missed?

Comment: You need to actually provide the error output.  Also, do not post images of text, post the text in the question.

Comment: problem is solved, see all page

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem, and for future i write my steps, how build V8 on macOS:

1. Build v8 engine without snapshot and as shared library for native platform: sudo make library=shared snapshot=off native;
2. Compile with clang (gcc throw error, like "undefined symbol for architecture..." etc ) but clang on mac compiles fine;
3. Copy from your ./out directory files with *./dylib to usr/local/lib

Comment: if you get a bunch of errors when linking with other programs, you may need to tell it to compile with libc++ instead of libstdc++.   See the env vars I set here: https://github.com/xaxxon/v8toolkit/blob/master/osx_v8_build.md   You will also need to copy a couple .a files from that directory, as not everything is built into a shared library.